# How to make a PVC pipe coming out of drywall pretty?

Tags: drywall

Is there a standard methodology for things like this? 1 1/2" PVC pipe for a sink drain.

I came across [ABS Plastic Round Escutcheon Plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CG4F47W) but it seems like home improvement stores don't carry these? Is there a more typical method? Do people just usually mud them in or use gap filler? (image at the bottom)

Same question for the flexible metal hose inlets. Yes, all of this is visible from the living area. Also anyone know if it's safe to scrape/sand off the purple stuff where it's exposed? I assume it's PVC glue/sealer?

Thank you!

[image: drywall with pipes protruding].

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Nice question, nicely stated. Hope to hear more from you!

Answer (score 1):

Escutcheon plates come in many styles. Most common being chrome plated. Personally I would take the PVC out and replace it with chrome metal pipe. It’s a little more expensive and slightly harder to work with but looks a lot nicer and is usually what is used when exposed. If you really want to keep the PVC it can always be painted with a plastic paint such as Krylon Fusion. You could fill the holes in the drywall and sand it smooth to alleviate the need for a plate. You may want to maintain a 1/8” gap and fill with caulking  to eliminate drywall mud cracking due to pipe movement.

Answer (score 0):

It’s called an escutcheon plate and they come in various sizes and some are split so you don’t have to take the drain apart. https://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Plumbing-Parts-Repair-Faucet-Parts-Repair-Escutcheons-Flanges/N-5yc1vZc6ao